# How to access the inside function of outer function using on click method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
var pick = {};

function pick0() {
  pick.value = document.getElementById('box00').getAttribute('data-value');
}

function myCheck() {
  function drop() {
    var content = document.getElementById('box');
    content.innerHTML = pick.value;
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#box00 {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="drop()"></div>
<br>
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="myCheck()">CHECK</button>
<br><br>
<div id="box00" data-value="0" onclick="pick0()">0</div>
```

These are my codes. In here I want to copy the value from "Box00" to "Box" after pressed the button. Without pressing the button I don't want to copy the value. I tried many ways but I can't find a way to fix this. I hope you understand my problem. Please help me.

Comment: At `myCheck` function you create `drop`, but dont call anything.

Comment: FYI, answering the question that you deleted earlier (I disagree with the community, I wouldn't have closed it): What you've called a "dynamic value" is a *JSX expression*. The content of the expression (the bit between the `{ }`) can be any JavaScript expression. The result of the expression will be inserted where you've used `{ }`. In contrast, the text you've used is just plain text. No expressions are used. Your examples result in exactly the same thing, but there would be a difference between `<h3>Ninja Warrior</h3>` and `<h3>{'Ninja'} Warrior</h3>`. The former ...

Comment: ...results in an `h3` with *one* text node in it. The latter results in an `h3` with *two* text nodes in it. You can't see the difference in the rendered result, but you could if you looked at the DOM tree. https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-ptolemy-ro8jq?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me what it is that you are trying to achieve through your nested functions.

You do have a problem with your actions because `drop()` assumes that `pick.value` will be set, but `pick.value` only gets set by calling `pick0()`.  We want clicking the button to work on its own.  Everything that you are trying to do can be handled by this function:

```
function myCheck() {
    // find the target "box" element
    var content = document.getElementById('box');
    // set the "box"'s content to the data-value from "box00"
    content.innerHTML = document.getElementById('box00').getAttribute('data-value');
}
```

It doesn't seem like you need click handlers on the two boxes themselves, unless you want to add other functionality.